# Jasmine Testing Async (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have to sleep for a short time, else it does not work but it seems like very bad design. Is there a better way of doing it?

init() changes the scope.list in a .then() function

```js
it('save data by getAllTodos', async function (){
            let data = [{description: "test", done: false, id: 1}]
            spyOn(BackendServiceMock, 'getAllTodos').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({data: data}))

            scope.init()
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1))

            expect(BackendServiceMock.getAllTodos).toHaveBeenCalled()
            expect(scope.list).toEqual(data)
        })
```

Thanks to Petr Averyanov I found the solution, I had to use $q

```js
it('save data by getAllTodos', function (){
            let data = [{description: "test", done: false, id: 1}]

            spyOn(BackendServiceMock, 'getAllTodos').and.returnValue(deffered.promise.then(value => value))

            scope.init()
            deffered.resolve({data: data})
            rootScope.$apply()

            expect(scope.list).toEqual(data)
        })
```

Comment: I see what you mean. AngularJS doesnt play well with async/await, hence your usage with .then. The way you have it is similar to the current Angular tick for mock testing. https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick. To make it "feel" better, you can write your own tick method and add your promise/resolve into the block and await that tick.

Comment: Is it Angularjs? why u dont use $q then? or it is Angular - what is scope then? I am confused here)

Comment: yes it is angularjs, i don't know about $q

Comment: thank petr it worked that way!